# Set private var string from input text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

The other day I tried setting a string var inside flash, I need somehow to set the var as the text box. I tried doing this:

```
private var name: String = fromthis.text;
```

and it doesn't work, anyone knows why?

Comment: It looks ok. Must be a problem elsewhere. Please post additional pertinent code, along with a description of where the code is (timeline, .as files, etc.). Also tell us what "it doesn't work" means. What do you expect to happen and what *is* happening.

Answer (score 0):

*If I guess the question correctly*:

```
private var name: String = fromthis.text;
```

means that you declare a variable called `name` and make its value equal to `fromthis.text` at that very moment. If you type something into `fromthis`, it doesn't change the `name` variable. You need to listen to `TextFiled` [`CHANGE` event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#event:change) to keep the variable up to date.

**update:**
You are getting `Error #1009` because `fromthis` is not visible from where you declare the `name` variable and so it is equal to `null`, which can't have any fields (including field called `text`), so you are getting this error. 
It may happen becuase it is not yet created at that moment or because the code is located inside of an `.as` class file and `fromthis` is located on the stage itself and thus can not be accessed like this.

**update 2:**
If `name` is located in a class file, and `fromthis` is just dragged into the stage in the editor, the best way would be to just pass it to the class constructor:

```
private var _tf:TextField;
function MyClass(tf:TextField){
    _tf = tf;
    //or if you need the string from textfield just once you may pass that string
}
```

And call the class constructor `new MyClass(fromthis)` (assuming you have access to `fromthis` at where you instantiate your class).

Comment: It returnes with this message: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: It is located in a class file, so is there a way I can locate it somehow?

Comment: I tried doing this, didn't work xD is there a video maybe of this?

Comment: @ProgramKiddo need more information. Where and when is `fromthis` created, where, when and how do you instantiate your class?

Comment: I just want it to load a text (input) to a function basically using this var

Comment: @ProgramKiddo and where do you call that function?